# Percentage edit distance from array

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, bioinformatics, edit-distance

I am attempting to get a percentage of an edit distance from a group of sequences. So far this is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);

my @sequence = qw(CA--------W----------------------EKDRRTEAF---F------ 
CA--------W----------------------EKDRRTEAF---F------ 
CA--------S-------------------SLVFGQGDNIQY---F------  
RA--------S-------------------SLIYSP----LH---F------);


foreach my $list (@sequence){
    my @distance = distance($list, @sequence);
    my @length = $list =~ tr/[A-Z]///;
}
```

I am able to get the edit distance with `@distance` and the length of each sequence, based on the letters with `@length`. If printed the results are as follows:

`@distance`

```
0 0 13 14
0 0 13 14
13 13 0 11 
14 14 11 0
```

`@length`

```
13
13
16
12
```

As each line of `@length` is equivalent to each line of `@sequence`, when comparing the two lines I would like to use the largest `@length` to get the percentage. So as when having an edit distance between the second and third sequence it would use the length of 16 rather than 13 to get a percentage. What I think needs to happen is to call only two elements of the `@length` array and pick the larger one to then put into a percentage, possibly using an `if` statement.

I know this code is wrong, but it is generally the idea I am going for:

```
foreach my  $list (@sequence){
        my @distance = distance($list, @sequence);      
        my @length = $list =~ tr/[A-Z]//;                # / syntax hilite fix

        foreach my $item(@distance){
                foreach @length {
                        my $num1 = if $length[0] >= $length[1];
                                 print "$item/$num1\n";
                        else my $num2 = $length[1] >= $length[0];
                                print "$item/$num2\n";
                }
        }
}
```

The answer should look something similar to that below:

```
0  0 .8125  1.0769
0  0  .8125  1.0769
.8125  .8125  0  .6875
1.0769  1.0769  .6875  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. To summarize: We compute the edit distances between pairs of 
strings. For each pair we want to determine the fraction of the distance and the maximum number of characters (`A-Z`). The maximum number of characters is taken to be the maximum for the two items in the pair.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);

my @sequence = qw(
        CA--------W----------------------EKDRRTEAF---F------
        CA--------W----------------------EKDRRTEAF---F------
        CA--------S-------------------SLVFGQGDNIQY---F------
        RA--------S-------------------SLIYSP----LH---F------
);

my @length = map { tr/[A-Z]// } @sequence;

for my $i (0..$#sequence) {
    my $list = $sequence[$i];
    my @distance = distance($list, @sequence);
    my $num1 = $length[$i];
    for my $j (0..$#distance) {
        my $item = $distance[$j];
        my $num2 = $length[$j];
        my $num = ( $num2 > $num1 ) ? $num2 : $num1;
        printf "%.4f ", $item/$num;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
0.0000 0.0000 0.8125 1.0769 
0.0000 0.0000 0.8125 1.0769 
0.8125 0.8125 0.0000 0.6875 
1.0769 1.0769 0.6875 0.0000
```

Comment: Nice work.  Btw, adding a comment like `# /` at the line with regex will turn off the wrong syntax highlight for the rest of the post.  Sometimes you have to play with it, depending on what in regex sets it off.  Here I'd expect `# /` to do it.

Comment: @zdim Thanks. [Seems like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) stackexchange.com uses [Google's code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). If you like, we could try fix some issues with Perl syntax highlighting on SO (seems like we need to write our patches in Javascript though :)) Have a nice Christmas from Norway.

Comment: Thank you for well wishes. I may have got a glimpse of Norway on an Oregon mountain, with feet of snow and lots of sunshine.  (But I somehow think that 20F was way too warm?) I hope you had a good holiday.

Comment: That is a very good idea, to actually fix things!  (I don't know how one goes about doing that.)  As for JS, it would be an opportunity for me to finally get into it.

Comment: @zdim Hi zdim. Actually the climate in Norway is quite varied. I live in Bergen at the west coast, and its not so cold here :) I have never been in Oregon, but I visited California 15 years ago... Anyway, I created a fork of Google's code-prettify GitHub repository. So let's continue the discussion [in it's issue tracker](https://github.com/hakonhagland/code-prettify/issues/1). See you.